# TabContainer from AJAX Toolkit not visible in browser (including ToolkitScriptManager)

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi I have Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web
I installed AJAX Control Toolkit .NET 4.5 from http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/109918

I added AjaxControlToolkit.dll to project resources, then I added it to ToolBox -> Choose items.

Everything works find in design mode, I can see the TabControl, but when I compile to a website, the control is not visible.

Visual Studio Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="JuwentWebASP_kurtyny.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <br />
        <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="479px">
            <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1" ID="TabPanel1">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    sdfsdfsfsdf
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
            <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    sdfdfsdfsdf
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:TabPanel>
        </asp:TabContainer>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Website source:
http://pastebin.com/YJSmAY1N

Comment: Do you have error messages in browser console?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net 4.0/4.5, check that you have added AjaxTookitScriptManager (and not ScriptManager usually added in .net 2.0). I ran into the same problem and figured that out from this notes: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/09/20/september-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution. I don't know exactly why but the `TabContainer` style is in `hidden` mode, I try this and works!

I hope this helps you.

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="479px"
style="width:900px;visibility:visible;">
```

Comment: style="width:900px;visibility:visible;" add to the tabcontainer